# determine chunk size of an existing raid array

Tags: raid, mdadm

What should I do to determine chuck size of existing raid arrays. I'm using software raid created by `mdadm`.

I've been probing around for a while and can't find the right utility to that job.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md/0

mdadm --examine /dev/sda0
```

and

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

doesn't say any thing about chunk size.

```
cat /sys/block/md0/md/chunk_size
```

returns `0`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can run

```
mdadm -E /dev/sda1
```

or similar against one of the devices in the array. It will print the superblock and lists the chunk size there. Note that the switch is `-E`, not `-e`.

See the third grey section [here](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2002/12/05/RAID.html?page=2)

EDIT:
See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/mdadm-raid1-and-what-chunksize-or-blocksize-on-4k-drives) and [here](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#RAID-1_2) on chunk size in RAID1

Comment: thanx for replying. i forgot to mention that i did call --examine on the device and nothing was printed about chunk-size. here's an [example output](http://paste2.org/p/1618308). is it my mdadm version (v3.1.4) or metadata version that makes the difference?

Comment: I've seen two thoughts on this. One, since RAID 1 doesn't stripe, chunk size is irrelevant. In another, it's only relevant to reads/seeks. My guess is, it wasn't set since it's RAID one, and if it has a value, it's the default 64k

Comment: Your output says you're using RAID1. See the comment and two links I've added above.

Comment: i'm aware that i was using the 64k default chunk-size. i've read the man pages and the wikipedia article before i asked the question. however, since "the chunk-size specifies how much data to read serially from the participating disks", it does matter for raid 1 arrays, doesn't it? i mean, it's supposed to take chunk-size into consideration tuning the filesystem lying on the array, right?